# Eclipse: Project > Properties does not show all the options

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have two work spaces, both for java projects.  One shows all the options in project properties (such as Java Build Path).  See the image below:
[image]

Other project project properties in another workspace does NOT show all the options (Java Build Path in particular).  See the Image below:

[image]

Note: The second project is a  maven project that i've checked out from an svn repository whereas, the first one is a java project (not checked-out).

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second project is not a Java project as far as Eclipse is concerned (technically it does not have the Java `nature` defined for the project in the `.project` file). Only Java projects have the property pages such as Java Build Path.